# IE & Edge hiding box shadow behind the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have input slider range where on thumb active `box-shadow` applied. In all browser the shadow showing perfectly but when IE & EDGE then shadow cutting/hiding behind parent div (`#c`).

**See I have used `overflow:visible` to this parent but still shadow cutting/hiding when you drag the thumb/pointer left or right end**

```css
#b {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}
input[type=range]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}
input[type=range]:active::-ms-thumb {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}
#c{
  width: 300px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
   <input id="b" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" class="slider-color" >
</div>
```

Even tried `position:relative;z-index:999` to `input[type=range]:active::-ms-thumb` but nothing happened. Can anybody help me

[image: windows 10, IE 11.6xx]

windows 10, IE 11.6xx

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

Comment: @לבנימלכה already checked this, there is no solution of that question

Comment: try :`#b{appearance: none;}`

Comment: @לבנימלכה not helped. tried

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the issue that you are facing? Apparently it works fine at my end for IE(11.0.9600.18665) Win7.

Comment: @Nik check my question, Screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

I think my point of view `pseudo selector` will not work based on attribute selection in `ie`. You have to use `selection` tag like `a` to apply `box-shadow`. The below code It works well in `edge, firefox, chrome` browsers. Comment for more information regarding this.

```css
#b {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
}

#c {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
}

input[type=range]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}

input[type=range]:active:-moz-range-track {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}

input[type=range]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}

input[type=range]:active::-ms-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}

input[type=range]:active::-ms-track {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}

input[type=range]:active::-ms-fill-lower {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}

input[type=range]:active::-ms-fill-upper {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
    <input id="b" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" class="slider-color">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## I hope its work on IE

```css
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 6px #e45685;
}
```